# Why is tension split evenly between the two rope segments in a two-pulley system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

I understand that the total tension to carry and move the weight would be split between the two segments of the two-pulley system, but I don't see why it would be evenly split between the two. It makes sense to me that if, say, a block were hanging from the ceiling by two strings attached at the ceiling, the weight would be split half and half since there's no distinguishing feature between the two strings. But if the strings were attached to two "ceilings" at two different heights, I'm not confident that wouldn't affect the weight distribution. Could anyone give an explanation of why it wouldn't?

Comment: If the tension were different there would be a moment around the axle of the pulley and it would rotate in until they are the same.

Comment: Ok, I see—it's to keep the pulley at equilibrium. If there were no pulley and it was just a block hanging by two strings attached from two different heights, would they necessarily have the same tension?

Comment: You could well have one string taking all the weight if they are separate.

Comment: This question must have been asked before.

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of any friction between the string and pulleys, the tension in a single continuous massless inextensible string is the same throughout the entire string.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

In this type of problems, the contact between string and pulley is supposed frictionless. If some small portion of the string had bigger force for one direction than the other, that portion would be accelerating. As the system is in equilibrium, the tension must be equal along it.

It is not exactly equal due to the weight of the string itself, but it is supposed to be too small compared to the load at the hook. So, for practical effects, the tension is constant.

Answer (score -1):

The tension in the string is T in all the sections including the third unmarked section on the extreme right. The top pulley has a clockwise torque due to the tension of the rightmost string and an anticlockwise torque due to the leftmost string. These torques on the top pulley are equal so it is in equilibrium. When the tension is increased on the right string, the opposing torques are no longer in equilibrium and the top pulley rotates clockwise, increasing the tension in the leftmost section of the string. This increased tension causes an imbalance on the torque of the lower pully and it also rotates clockwise (raising the weight) until the tension in the string is equal everywhere (and equal to T) once again and all the torques are equal again. Equilibrium = equal tension everywhere in the string. For this reason the tension in the left string and the middle string (and the right string) is always equal as long as the pully wheels are free to turn and the system is in equilibrium.